# Single file download feature from remote server in phpStorm?

Tags: netbeans, ftp, ide, phpstorm, sftp

I have recently shifted to phpStorm from NetBeans.

I know I can select to download the single or multiple files from remote server when creating the project. So, I only downloaded some necessary files which need to be edited for the project. But after creating the project I realized that I want to download another specific file from a folder to the project not downloading or syncing the whole folder. How can I do that?

Please see the below NetBeans feature which I am expecting.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use **Remote Host** side panel (can also be accessed via `Tools | Deployment | Browse Remote Host` if panel is closed) and download any files you want.

Comment: It says "No files or folders found to process"

Comment: @zhilevan So .. it must be some sort of misconfiguration from your end. See -- the guy had the same issue and then he managed it by fixing his own mistake that he did at some point earlier.

Comment: @LazyOne tnx for your attention, in first initial I exclude some path , then  know I want download  a directory , in Remote Host I first right-click on it and remove "exclude" check, then right-click and try to download, but "No files or folders found to process" , where is my mistake?

Comment: @zhilevan 1) Are you able to deploy your files to remote host at all? 2) Go to your `Tools | Deployment | Configuration` and make sure that you have configured it correctly (e.g. points to correct folders/uses correct login details). Try also removing any entries from Excluded list.

Comment: @LazyOne yes, everything with other files is ok ( field that I download them in initial of project, I can download, upload, sync them ). my problem is only when I want download a directory that I exclude them in initial of project .

Comment: @zhilevan So have you tried un-excluding it? If anything -- delete that Deployment entry and create another one from scratch -- maybe it will help this way.

Comment: @LazyOne I told you before, yes, in Remote Host I right-click on that directory and remove exclude check.  I have this problem with another projects , I dont want in start of project download all ftp files (they are too much) , I just want  download and work when I want ( download them and work with them ).

Comment: @zhilevan So work with them. You exclude files from **initial** downloading where wizard downloads all except excluded. but once you start working with actual project, you may remove all remote exclusions as in this case you are the one who controls what to do. In other words -- you may ignore "create new project from exiting files" wizard altogether -- just create empty new local project and then do the rest manually (configure deployment and download whatever files you need).

Comment: @zhilevan Question is -- does it work for you when you have no exclusion at all or not. If it works then all good here -- because that's the point for exclusion list -- to not to operate with such files. If it does not (i.e. exclusion list is completely empty before you start browsing remote host) then there must be some issue.

Comment: @LazyOne It work correctly if I have no exclusion list, but I want something I could use in netbeans IDE before, download directory that I didn't use them ( download them ) ( I put them I exclude list ) . but now when I want download them , first remove exclude  check in remote server on my desire folder then  try download it not it say "No files or folders found to process".  in local it is not exists but in remote exist and I remove it from exclude, I expect phpstorm create a folder as the same name in local and download it ( Netbeans do something like this )

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it.

At first I needed to Remove the Path from "Excluded Paths" panel.

Then I was able to download the file by right click and Selecting "Download from here".

Comment: When I try Download from here  it told me "No files or folders found to process" !!!!